# Black tab bar appears while pushing SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm using the following code to present an SFSafariViewController

```
    let url = "https://stackoverflow.com"
    let safariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    safariViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    safariViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    self.navigationController?.present(safariViewController, animated: true)
```

For some reason, t[image]here is a glitch in the SFSafariViewController upon presenting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my problem 
My  UINavigationBar style was set to black
    `UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black`